# multiple dynamic selects using AJAX

Tags: forms, ajax

The dynamic selects are populated via radio button selection. The first choice works fine but the second throws 'An illegal choice has been detected...' error. It does not matter which, of the two, is selected first. The form will, eventually, have five dynamic selections. I've modified and condensed the relevant code, which I've included below (sorry to post 100 lines of code).

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the error and how to cure it?

```
function _wauco_construction_get_components_dropdown($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    t('Face') => array( 'one' => t('Facestock1'), 'two' => t('Facestock2'), 'three' => t('Facestock3'), 'four' => t('Facestock4')),
    t('Liner') => array( 'one' => t('Liner1'),  'two' => t('Liner2'),  'three' => t('Liner3'),  'four' => t('Liner4')),
    t('Adhesive') => array( 'one' => t('Adhesive1'), 'two' => t('Adhesive2'), 'three' => t('Adhesive3'), 'four' => t('Adhesive4')),
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
}

function wauco_construction_dropdown_callback_one($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['component_one']['select'];
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function wauco_construction_dropdown_callback_two($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['component_two']['select'];
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}

function form_construction_create ($form, &$form_state) {
  $radio_options = drupal_map_assoc(array(t('Face'), t('Liner'), t('Adhesive')));
  $selected_one = isset($form_state['values']['component_one']['radios']) ? $form_state['values']['component_one']['radios'] : key($radio_options);
  $selected_two = isset($form_state['values']['component_two']['radios']) ? $form_state['values']['component_two']['radios'] : key($radio_options);

  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['construction_info'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Please chose the construction\'s components and functions from the items below.'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="components-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['construction_info']['construction_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Construction Name:'),
  );

  $form['construction_info']['catalog_number'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Catalog Number:'),
  );

  // component one input

  $form['component_one'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'component_one',
    '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['component_one']['radios'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Function:',
    '#options' => $radio_options,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('enabled-for-ajax')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'wauco_construction_dropdown_callback_one',
      'wrapper' => 'component_select-replace-one',
     ),
  );

  $form['component_one']['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $radio_options[$selected_one] . ' ' . t('Components'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component_select-replace-one">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('enabled-for-ajax')),
    '#options' => _wauco_construction_get_components_dropdown($selected_one),
  );

  // component two input

  $form['component_two'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'component_two',
    '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['component_two']['radios'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => 'Function:',
    '#options' => $radio_options,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('enabled-for-ajax')),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'wauco_construction_dropdown_callback_two',
      'wrapper' => 'component_select-replace-two',
     ),
  );

  $form['component_two']['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => $radio_options[$selected_two] . ' ' . t('Components'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="component_select-replace-two">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('enabled-for-ajax')),
    '#options' => _wauco_construction_get_components_dropdown($selected_two),
  );


  return $form;

} // end function form_construction_create
```

Comment: I have additional information but am not sure what it means. The following appear in the log when the error condition is generated:

Notice: Undefined index: in form_construction_create() (line 101 of E:\www\drupal\modules\wauco_data\wauco_construction_create.inc).

Illegal choice one in Components element.

What do these mean?

Comment: The "illegal choice" error is shown when in the form field has been selected an option that Drupal would not expect. Check how the options are build.